# I may be large, or I may be small - A 'Riley Riddle'

Tags: riddle, affix-riddle

> My prefix likes to compare.
> My infix is fairly studious.
> My suffix is rather polite.
> I may be large, or I may be small.

**What am I?**

<sup>*NB The suffix description was edited because "polite" seemed more appropriate than "formal".*</sup>

Hint 1:

> The prefix, infix and suffix do not overlap.

Hint 2:

> If you want a good example of me, don't look any farther than where you're at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are a:

> community

My prefix likes to compare.

> Comm is a unix command that compares two text files and displays the differences

My infix is fairly studious.

> Uni, or university

My suffix is rather polite.

> Ty, shorthand for thank you

I may be large, or I may be small.

> Depending on who you ask, our community (Puzzling.Stackexchange) could be large or it could be small!

Comment: I was hoping my last hint made it a lot easier XD. Good job, this is correct.

Answer (score 14):

I'll take a guess.  Are you:

> an **intestine?**

My prefix likes to compare.

> 'In' is a comparative preposition

My infix is fairly studious.

> 'Test' is a school exam

My suffix is rather formal.

> '-ine' is a suffix of scientific classification

I may be large, or I may be small.

> Referring to the small intestine and large intestine

Comment: +! for a great guess, unfortunately, it's incorrect. There will be a more clear link to comparison for the prefix.

Answer (score 5):

An answer with a bit of an infix stretch:

> Organisms

The comparative prefix is:

> Or, as in "either x or y"

The rather formal suffix:

> Ms, the title for a female

And now for the studious infix:

> [Ganis](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=xwJfzzwAAAAJ&hl=en) - this guy clearly fits the bill :)

And, of course,

> Organisms can be both large (e.g. elephants) and small (e.g. bacteria).

Answer (score 3):

You are

> an **eraser**.

> My prefix likes to compare.

> **Er** is a suffix that commonly forms comparatives.

> My infix is fairly studious.

> **A** is commonly the highest letter grade, obtainable by being studious.

> My suffix is rather formal.

> **Ser** sounds like *sir*, an honorific. Apparently, [*ser*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ser#Noun) is also used in some fantasy novels as a gender-neutral version.

> I may be large, or I may be small.

> You come in large parallelepiped form and small pencil form.

Comment: The prefix will be directly related to comparison in some way. Yours is a tad bit of a stretch, but nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

My try.  Are you:

> a contestant?

My prefix likes to compare.

> 'Con' usually means with, so you compare those you are with.

My infix is fairly studious.

> 'Test' is a school exam - Credit to TwoBitOperation

My suffix is rather formal.

> 'ant' is a suffix usually denoting someone who does something, often service. So, a formal servant.

I may be large, or I may be small.

> Gymnasts are small, basketball players large.

Comment: +1 for good attempt, but the suffix's link to formality will be more obvious than that. The infix, however, may be less obvious.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a stretch but maybe

> an Android

My prefix likes to compare.

> "and" the logical conjunction that compares 2 logicacl and is true only if both are true

My infix is fairly studious.

> "rho" the greek letter often used in science

My suffix is rather formal.

> an "ID" is a formal document

I may be large, or I may be small.

> androids are human-like robots but also the name of a smartphone OS

Comment: Yes, there will be a more clear link to description for the infix, but clever idea.